# How to use JPQL SIZE() correctly?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I can't get the `SIZE(collection_valued_path_expression)` function in JPQL to work. Here is a test I have tried:

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> children;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

**Child.java**

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ...
    EntityManager em = dao.getEntityManager();

    Parent p = new Parent();

    Child a = new Child();
    Child b = new Child();
    Child c = new Child();
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
    children.add(a); children.add(b); children.add(c);

    p.setChildren(children);

    em.persist(p);

    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p.id, SIZE(p.children) FROM Parent p");

    Object[] row = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();

    System.out.println(row[0]);
    System.out.println(row[1]);

    em.close();
}
```

**Console**

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.

What am I doing wrong? Tried this with [EclipseLink 2.3.2 and 2.5.1](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/previous_releases.php), the database is MySQL.

Comment: tried doing a flush() before the query? FlushMode on the query should handle this but may be worth a try

Comment: I have tried it with manual transaction handling and `em.flush()`, but it did not help unfortunately.

Comment: and the SQL executed is? INSERTs get to the DB before the query? and the query SQL is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EclipseLink log has revealed that the produced query was:

> SELECT t0.ID, COUNT(t1.ID) FROM PARENT t0, CHILD t1 WHERE (t1.PARENT_ID = t0.ID) GROUP BY t0.ID, t0.ID

I have found that the foreign key column `t1.PARENT_ID` was `null` every time. I have changed my persist order the following way:

```java
EntityManager em = dao.getEntityManager();

Parent p = new Parent();

em.persist(p);

Child a = new Child(); a.setParent(p);
Child b = new Child(); b.setParent(p);
Child c = new Child(); c.setParent(p);

em.persist(a);
em.persist(b);
em.persist(c);
```

Then I got a result and the desired output:

> 651
>
> 3